# Set invariant under group action

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, matrix-decomposition, invariant-theory, orthogonal-matrices

I am reading a paper with the following description:

1. $O(n): \{Y\in \mathbf{R}^{n\times n}\mid Y^TY=I\}$

[image]

We say a set $V$ is $T$-invariant if $TV\subseteq V$, where $T$ is a linear transform. So according to the article

1. $T$ should be $(U,V)\cdot X$
2. $UXV^T\in \mathbf{R}^{n\times n}$; therefore, $\mathbf{R}^{n\times n}$ is invariant under the group action.

> Why does the paper says "This action leaves the set $O(n)$ invariant"?   $UXV^T\notin O(n)$.

Comment: If $X\in O(n)$ then $UXV^T\in O(n)$.