# Polar of orthogonal set invariant under group action

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, matrix-decomposition, invariant-theory, orthogonal-matrices

I just ask the following question:

[Set invariant under group action](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1851364/set-invariant-under-group-action)

> Furthermore, How to prove the green part

[image]

Original paper: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.4914v1.pdf  (p.1324)

Let $$O(n)=\{X\in \mathbf{R}^{n\times n}\mid X^TX=I\}.$$

Its polar:    $$O(n)^o=\{Y\in \mathbf{R}^{n\times n}\mid \langle Y,X\rangle\leq 1,\forall X\in O(n)\}.$$

---

My proof:

Suppose $Y=U\Sigma V^T\Rightarrow \Sigma=U^TYV$ (singular value decomposition).

I want to show $\langle U_1YV_1^T,X \rangle \leq 1$, for all $X\in O(n)$.

Let $U_1=U^T, V_1=V$, then it becomes $\langle \Sigma,X \rangle $, for all $X\in O(n)$.

Can I say $\langle \Sigma,X \rangle \leq 1$?

I have no idea how to prove or even this way is wrong. How to prove the green part?